# Align Label at top left input form

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to do is to align the label at top left form box and Radio button next to label. So it looks more clean. I've messed around with the CSS but still couldn't get it right.

This is the **CSS** I'm using:

```css
input{
        width:190px;
        border:1px solid #ccc;
}
select{
        width:190px;
        border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/4tdcbvkg/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by simply adding a little more CSS:

```css
input {
  width: 190px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

select {
  width: 190px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

td {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="8" class="begoneee" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td class="begoneee"> <span class="merah">*</span> Project ID</td>
    <td class="begoneee"> <span class="merah">*</span>Project Name</td>
    <td class="begoneee">Category</td>
    <td class="begoneee">Project Status</td>
    <td><label>Project Type:</label><br/>
      <input type="radio" name="input3" onclick="streamverify(0)">Upstream<br/>
      <input type="radio" name="input3" onclick="streamverify(1)">Downstream<br/>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="begoneee"><input type="text" id="proj_id" style="background-color:#f2f2f2" readonly></td>
    <td class="begoneee"><input type="text" id="proj_name"></td>
    <td class="begoneee">
      <select id="category">
           <option value="blank"> </option>
     <option value="pcd">PCD</option>
     <option value="ons">Onshore</option>
     <option value="offs">Offshore</option>
     <option value="fip">FIP</option>
   </select></td>
    <td class="begoneee">
      <select id="proj_status">
           <option value="blank"> </option>
     <option value="inpg">In Progress</option>
     <option value="comp">Completed</option>
     <option value="canc">Cancelled</option>
     <option value="oh">On Hold</option>
     <option value="exo">Expense Off</option>
     <option value="op">Open</option>
     <option value="arc">Archived</option></td>
    </tr>
 
 <tr>
        <td class="begoneee">Region</td>
        <td class="begoneee">OPU</td>
  <td class="begoneee">Operator/Asset owner</td>
  <td class="begoneee">Project Status</td>
  <td class="begoneee">Project Phase/Delivery</td>
  <td class="begoneee">Project Start Date</td>
        <td class="begoneee">Project End Date</td>

 
    </tr>
 
     <tr>
        <td class="begoneee">
  <select id="region" >
           <option value="blank"> </option>
     <option value="jda">Joint Development Area</option>
     <option value="pm">Pen 2332EDQWSWACF</option>
     <option value="sbh">Sabah</option>
     <option value="srwk">sarawak</option>
     <option value="na">N/A</option>
   </select></td>
    <td class="begoneee">
      <select id="opu">
           <option value="blank"> </option>
     <option value="pchemical_g">APDAOCIJCMICAC Chemicals Group</option>
     <option value="asean">Asean Bintulu Fertiliser Sdn Bhd</option>
     <option value="fertilizer">APDAOCIJCMICAC Chemicals Fertilizer Kedah  Sdn Bhd</option>
     <option value="pchemical_m">APDAOCIJCMICAC Chemicals Marketing (LABUAN) Ltd  </option>
     <option value="pmetha">APDAOCIJCMICAC Chemicals Methanol Sdn Bhd</option>
     <option value="pmtbe">APDAOCIJCMICAC Chemicals MTBE Sdn Bhd</option>
     <option value="pmp">Polypropylene (M) Sdn Bhd</option>
     <option value="pchemical_e">APDAOCIJCMICAC Chemicals Ethylene Sdn Bhd</option>
     <option value="kertih">Kertih Port Sdn. Bhd</option>
     <option value="aromatic"> Aromatics 2332EDQWSWACF Sdn Bhd</option>
     <option value="pchemical_a">APDAOCIJCMICAC Chemicals Ammonia Sdn Bhd</option>
     <option value="pchemical_f"> APDAOCIJCMICAC Chemicals Fertiliser Sabah Sdn Bhd</option>
     <option value="pchemical_o"> APDAOCIJCMICAC Chemicals Olefins Sdn Bhd</option>
     <option value="pchemical_d">APDAOCIJCMICAC Chemicals Derivatives Sdn Bhd</option>
     <option value="pchemical_gg"> APDAOCIJCMICAC Chemicals Glycols Sdn Bhd </option>
     <option value="pchemical_ldpe"> APDAOCIJCMICAC Chemicals LDPE Sdn Bhd</option>
     <option value="pchemical_cgbp">APDAOCIJCMICAC Chemicals Group Berhad </option>
     <option value="p_trg">APDAOCIJCMICAC Penapisan Terengganu Sdn Bhd </option>
     <option value="pgb">PGB </option>
     <option value="mlng"> MLNG</option>
     <option value="pdagangan"> APDAOCIJCMICAC Dagangan Berhad</option>
     <option value="my-refining">2332EDQWSWACFn Refining Company Sdn Bhd (MRCSB) </option>
     <option value="penapisan">APDAOCIJCMICAC Penapisan (Melaka) Sdn Bhd (PP(M)SB) </option>
     <option value="2QEDFCACFZCZ-ober-sea"> APDAOCIJCMICAC 2QEDFCACFZCZ Oversea Sdn Bhd (subsidiaries)</option>
     <option value="2QEDFCACFZCZ-sdn"> APDAOCIJCMICAC 2QEDFCACFZCZ Sdn Bhd</option>
     <option value="pflng"> PFLNG</option>

   </select></td>
    <td class="begoneee"><input type="text" name="ccc"></td>
    <td class="begoneee"><input type="text" name="proj_status"></td>
    <td class="begoneee"><select id="proj_delivery">
           <option value="blank"> </option>
     <option value="framing">Framing</option>
     <option value="fel1">FEL-1</option>
     <option value="fel2">FEL-2</option>
     <option value="fel3">FEl-3</option>
     <option value="fid">FID</option>
     <option value="exec">Execution</option>
     <option value="stp">Start-up/Cost</option>
     <option value="closure">Closure</option>
     <option value="abd">Abandonment & Decommissioning</option>
     <option value="dev">Development</option>
     <option value="exp">Exploration</option>
     <option value="intv">Intervation</option>
     </td>
     
     <td class="begoneee"><input type="text"></td>
     <td class="begoneee"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td class="begoneee">Cost Category</td>
  <td class="begoneee">Currency</td>

    </tr>
 
     <tr>
           <td class="begoneee">
    <select id="cost_category">
           <option value="blank"> </option>
     <option value="opex">OPEX</option>
     <option value="capex">CAPEX</option>
     </td>
    </select>
      <td class="begoneee">
        <select id="currency">
           <option value="blank"> </option>
     <option value="opex">MYR</option>
     <option value="capex">USD</option>
     <option value="capex">SGD</option>
     <option value="capex">Yen</option>
     </td>
    </select>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It works but one more this is the radio button. i've included this css but doesnt change anything too.

Comment: input[type="radio"] {
    margin-left:10px;
}

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

i did some improvements in your css:

```css
input[type="text"]{
    width:190px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
select{
    width:190px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
label{
  display: block;
}
td{
  padding-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```